# Reading a requested JSON file in pandas

Tags: json, pandas, request

I am learning how to work with JSON files in Pandas.

A publicly available JSON file with data can be read by the following lines of code:

```
import requests 
import json
url = 'https://data.seattle.gov/resource/65db-xm6k.json'
response = requests.get(url) 
data_json = response.json()
```

How do I sort data_json on columns so I can further process it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as reading the json file in `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data_json)
df

    date                      fremont_bridge    fremont_bridge_sb   fremont_bridge_nb
0   2012-10-03T00:00:00.000   13                4                   9
1   2012-10-03T01:00:00.000   10                4                   6
2   2012-10-03T02:00:00.000   2                 1                   1
3   2012-10-03T03:00:00.000   5                 2                   3
4   2012-10-03T04:00:00.000   7                 6                   1
... ...                       ...               ...                 ...
```